# How would i make a code that creates a new list

Tags: python-3.x

I want this code to run so every time i use this sub routine, a new list will be created. I am on a task where I am not allowed to use 3D arrays, and so i need to make a new list each time. My current code is this:

```
def lemon(a, b):

    week = []
    unsplit_data = input("Input the data for week " + a + " for " + b + " in order of bus A, bus B etc. Sperate these by a comma and a space eg. '1, 2, ': ")
    BA, BB, BC, BD, BE, BF = unsplit_data.split(', ')
    BA, BB, BC, BD, BE, BF = int(BA), int(BB), int(BC), int(BD), int(BE), int (BF)
    week = [BA, BB, BC, BD, BE, BF]
    print (week)


lemon('1', 'Monday')
```

This obviously produces one list, but i need it to make a new one each time it is run

Comment: why all the in betweens? `week = list(map(int, unsplit_data.split(', ')))` - if you need it elsewhere: `return week`. I suggest following a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution would be to use list comprehensions.
What you do is create a list using a for loop containing `input`.

**Python 3.6+**:

```
def lemon(a, b):
    week = [int(input(f'Please input data for week {a} for {b} for bus {chr(bus)}: ')) for bus in range(ord('A'), ord('F')+1)]
    return week
```

**Python 3+**:

```
def lemon(a, b):
    week = [int(input('Please input data for week {} for {} for bus {}: '.format(a, b, chr(bus)))) for bus in range(ord('A'), ord('F')+1)]
    return week


lemon('1', 'Monday')
```

[Some reading material about f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

You should however try and catch exceptions, in case a number was not added, as such:

```
def lemon(a, b):
    try:
        week = [int(input(f'Please input data for week {a} for {b} for bus {chr(bus)}: ')) for bus in range(ord('A'), ord('F')+1)]
        return week
    except ValueError:
        print('Not a number given.')
    return None


lemon('1', 'Monday')
```

Comment: How would i be able to recall each of these lists?

Comment: When you call `lemon('1', 'Monday')` it will return the list. What you can do is save it into a variable like `someweek = lemon('1', 'Monday')` or just print it `print(lemon('1', 'Monday'))`.